# Second or third conditional?

Tags: past-tense

Is the writer using second conditional here?

> "Imagine if Holden Caulfield **kept** his attitudes and opinions to himself and told the story straight. Imagine if Huckleberry Finn **did**. **If that was the case**, there wouldn't be a lot of heart and soul left in either of those wonderful first person narrative novels."

Second conditional is about the future (example: *If I did hit you what would you do?*), But in the paragraph above there's this "*If that was the case*" that makes it sound like he is talking about the past since it's not "*Had kept and had done*"

Answer (score 1):

These are "second conditional" statements talking about the present.

See [Perfect English Grammar](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/second-conditional.html), which states that the "second conditional" can be used to talk about either the present  or the future (which are both non-past).

One way to conceive of the  selected text  is

> If (it *was* the case that) Holden Caulfield *kept* his attitudes and opinions to himself and *told* the story straight (and if Huckleberry Finn *did* the same),   then there *wouldn't be* a lot of heart and soul left...

The simple past tense in the if-clause and the use of *would* plus infinitive in the then-clause is a textbook example of the second conditional.

> The second conditional uses the past simple after if, then 'would' and the infinitive

(From the Perfect Grammar website).